# Flow (InferError): Cannot get 'object[key]' because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing in 'Class'

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Here's my code to test equality of some class objects. See my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839801/jest-js-error-received-serializes-to-the-same-string) if you want to know why I'm not just doing
`expect(receivedDeals).toEqual(expectedDeals)` and other simpler assertions.

```js
   type DealCollection = { [key: number]: Deal };  // imported from another file

   it("does the whole saga thing", async () => {
      sagaStore.dispatch(startAction);
      await sagaStore.waitFor(successAction.type);
      const calledActionTypes: string[] = sagaStore
        .getCalledActions()
        .map(a => a.type);
      expect(calledActionTypes).toEqual([startAction.type, successAction.type]);
      const receivedDeals: DealCollection = sagaStore.getLatestCalledAction()
        .deals;
      Object.keys(receivedDeals).forEach((k: string) => {
        const id = Number(k);
        const deal = receivedDeals[id];
        const expected: Deal = expectedDeals[id];
        for (let key in expected) {
          if (typeof expected[key] === "function") continue;
          expect(expected[key]).toEqual(deal[key]);
        }
      });
    });
```

The test passes fine, but I'm getting a Flow error on `expected[key]`:

```
Cannot get 'expected[key]' because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing in 'Deal'
```

I can paste in code from `Deal` by request, but I think all you need to know is that I haven't declared an index signature (because I don't know how!).

I've searched around a bit but I can't find this exact case.

Update: I can eliminate the errors by changing `deal` and `expected` thusly:

```js
const deal: Object = { ...receivedDeals[id] };
const expected: Object = { ...expectedDeals[id] };
```

And since I'm comparing properties in the loop this isn't really a problem. But I would think that I should be able to do this with `Deal`s, and I'd like to know how I declare the index signature mentioned in the error.

PS. Bonus question: In some world where a mad scientist crossbred JS with Swift, I imagine you could do something like

```js
const deal: Object = { ...receivedDeals[id] where (typeof receivedDeals[id] !== "function" };
const expected = // same thing
expect(deal).toEqual(expected);

// And then after some recombining of objects:
expect(receivedDeals).toEqual(expectedDeals);
```

Is this a thing at all?

### Edit:

Adding a bit of the definition of `Deal` class:

#### Deal.js (summary)

```js
export default class Deal {
  obj: { [key: mixed]: mixed };
  id: number;
  name: string;
  slug: string;
  permalink: string;
  headline: string;
  // ...other property definitions

  constructor(obj?: Object) {
    if (!obj) return;
    this.id = obj.id;
    this.name = obj.name;
    this.headline = obj.headline;
    // ...etc
  }

  static fromApi(obj: Object): Deal {
    const deal = new Deal();
    deal.id = obj.id;
    deal.name = obj.name;
    deal.slug = obj.slug;
    deal.permalink = obj.permalink;
    // ...etc
    return deal;
  }

  descriptionWithTextSize(size: number): string {
    return this.descriptionWithStyle(`font-size:${size}`);
  }

  descriptionWithStyle(style: string): string {
    return `<div style="${style}">${this.description}</div>`;
  }

  distanceFromLocation = (
    location: Location,
    unit: unitOfDistance = "mi"
  ): number => {
    return distanceBetween(this.location, location);
  };

  distanceFrom = (otherDeal: Deal, unit: unitOfDistance = "mi"): number => {
    return distanceBetween(this.location, otherDeal.location);
  };

  static toApi(deal: Deal): Object {
    return { ...deal };
  }

  static collectionFromArray(array: Object[]) {
    const deals: DealCollection = {};
    array.forEach(p => (deals[p.id] = Deal.fromApi(p)));
    return deals;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An index signature (or indexer property) is defined as `[keyName: KeyType]: ValueType`. `DealCollection` is a great example: the `keyName` is `key`, the `KeyType` is `number` and the `ValueType` is `Deal`. This means that whenever you access a number property of an object of type `DealCollection`, it will return a `Deal`. You will want to add a similar expression to the definition of `Deal` in order to access arbitrary properties on it. More information can be found at the [Objects as maps](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps) section in the Flow documentation.

Comment: Thanks, and I think I understand what you're saying. But what is the syntax of the expression to add? I'd tried adding `{ [key: mixed]: mixed };` with the property definitions (see the code for `Deal` that I've added above; before adding any attempt at a signature) but that is a big syntax error. I changed it to `  obj: { [key: mixed]: mixed };` but that has no effect on the Flow errors.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue now. Flow types the return of `Object.keys` as a `string[]` so Flow will not be able to infer that `deal[key]` is defined. I don't know if there's a good Flow solution for that. However, I would recommend using [`toMatchObject`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject) and/or [`expect.any(Function)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectanyconstructor) instead of doing a loop through all of the keys.